# Как работает recvfrom?

Tags: c++

Я не могу понять почему `recvfrom` ожидает, разве он не должен сработать без задержки и выдать ошибку `SOCKET_ERROR`.
На данный момент мой `recvfrom` чего то ждем, не пойми чего.
Отладка показывает что на этом моменте код зависает и дальше не идет, более того я не могу проверить в чем дело, если код не пойдет дальше.

Comment: Сокет как сервер? т.е. ожидает подключения и приема данных?

Comment: Да как сервер, но ожидать не должен я понимаю есть recv для этого, но это recvfrom

Comment: что `recvfrom`, что `recv` в общем случае будут ждать поступления данных в сокет... для того что бы они этого не делали нужно перевести сокет в неблокирующий режим...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно он работает - по умолчанию, сокет создается блокирующим, так что если никто не присылает в него пакетики, он будет стоять и ждать.

Решение - таки отправьте в него данные, либо сделайте неблокирующим.

Дополнительно - перед вызовом recfrom, можно использовать всеразличные техники опроса, проверяющие, пришли ли байты в буфер. Это вызовы `select`, `poll` и подобные

Comment: Как сделать его неблокирующим?

Comment: @DarthVader У socket() есть флаг SOCK_NONBLOCK во втором аргументе. Или же на уже открытом сокете можно через fcntl()

Comment: SOCK_NONBLOCK не работает, я прочитал в интернете написано что он есть только в linux как мне быть?

Comment: @DarthVader `O_NONBLOCK` ?

Comment: O_NONBLOCK  тоже не работает.

Comment: @DarthVader, а вообще посетите вот эту страницу: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/

Comment: Документация помогла спасибо, если кому будет нужно вот ссылка это то что нужно, можно добавить в ответ
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-ioctlsocket

Comment: @DarthVader сто́ит указывать в вопросе, что вас интересуют ответы только для какой-то конкретной ОС. Иначе предполагается, что для любой :)